# saving file names into a txt file and copying files into a directory query

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

-**I tried the script below but the script is copying batch file names and pythonw.exe into the found_file.txt file and also it is not displaying anything in the found files folder. If anyone would look into it and help me out, I'd appreciate it.**

The code is below.

```
import shutil

path = 'C:'
FileList = []

extension = '.pdf' and '.docx' and '.jpeg'

# Scanning For Files :-

with os.scandir(path) as DirList:
    for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(path):
        for file_name in files_list:
            if os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] == extension:
                file_name_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
    for files in DirList:
        if files.is_file():
            FileList.append(files.name)

# After that it iterates over the FileList and write names to text file
with open("found_file.txt", 'w') as ffile:
    for fname in files_list:
        ffile.write(fname)
#copies all files into a folder called found_files
newPath = shutil.copy('files_list', 'C:/Users/PacY/Downloads/found_files')
```

Comment: `extension = '.pdf' and '.docx' and '.jpeg'` does not work

Comment: @kigawas what can work? I want all pdf, jpeg and docx file names to be copied into a txt file named found_file.txt and also to all those files to be copied to a folder called found_files

Comment: You have to make a list and iterate through them

Comment: @Matiiss may please help me with making a list and iteration. If you may edit the code for me. that'd be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the immediate action would be this:

```
import shutil

path = 'C:'
FileList = []

extensions = ['.pdf', '.docx', '.jpeg']

# Scanning For Files :-

with os.scandir(path) as DirList:
    for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(path):
        for file_name in files_list:
            # this loops over each extensions and evaluates it
            for extension in extensions:
                if os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] == extension:
                    file_name_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                    # break here so that if matching extension is found it stops checking
                    break
    for files in DirList:
        if files.is_file():
            FileList.append(files.name)

# After that it iterates over the FileList and write names to text file
with open("found_file.txt", 'w') as ffile:
    for fname in files_list:
        ffile.write(fname)
#copies all files into a folder called found_files
newPath = shutil.copy('files_list', 'C:/Users/PacY/Downloads/found_files')
```

You should learn about this because those are the basics. also if the code does not work feel free to ask questions. also isn't there a specific function for this? (not that I would know)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the help. I am newbie to python. after running the program I'm getting this error. ``  File "C:\Users\PacY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 415, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\PacY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'files_list' ``

Comment: @Uregem ok if it is in this part of the code then it has to do with `shutil.copy()`, You either have to have that directory in the same folder as this file or type the whole path instead of just `'files_list'`.