# I have a python script to list files in a path, how do I filter files with specific extensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a specific path with folders and files. I want to filter out files with pdf, docx,jpg extensions.

Already, I have a script to list all files. So I got stuck. Anyone who could help me out to filter out those files.

The code is below.

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users\PacY\Documents'
FileList = []

extensions = ['.pdf', '.docx', '.jpg']


for FileList in os.listdir(path):
    print("\nFiles: ", FileList)
```

Comment: well, it is a pretty straight forward concept. You split the names by `.` using `.split('.')`. that will return a list and You select last item in it and then evaluate it against whatever You need.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66884532/saving-file-names-into-a-txt-file-and-copying-files-into-a-directory-query?noredirect=1#comment118230779_66884532

Comment: if You follow the code previously mentioned You will se how extensions are evaluated

Comment: `filename.endswith( ['.pdf', '.docx', '.jpg'] )`

Comment: you can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), there are even example with regular expression for 'gif' file: `glob.glob('*.gif')`

Answer (score 1):

`listdir()` gives file names as strings and string has function `endswith()` (`ends with`) which can get single string (ie. `filename.endswith('.pdf')`) or tuple of strings (ie. `filename.endswith( ('.pdf', '.docx', '.jpg') )`)

```
import os

path = r'C:\Users\PacY\Documents'

extensions = ('.pdf', '.docx', '.jpg')  # has to be tuple instead of list

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith( extensions ):
        print("filename:", filename)
```

To make sure you can also convert name to `lower()` to recognize also  `.PDF`, `.Pdf`, etc.

```
    if filename.lower().endswith( extensions ):
```

---

```
import os

path = r'C:\Users\PacY\Documents'

extensions = ('.pdf', '.docx', '.jpg')  # has to be tuple instead of list

filtered_filenames = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.lower().endswith( extensions ):
        #print("filename:", filename)
        filtered_filenames.append(filename)
        #filtered_filenames.append( os.path.join(path, filename) )  # full path

print(filtered_filenames)
```

---

**by the way:**

it works also with extensions which have more dots - like `.pdf.zip` or popular on linux `.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `split` method. Here an example printing all the files in a folder that have one of those extensions.

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users\PacY\Documents'
FileList = []
 
extensions = ['pdf', 'docx', 'jpg']

FileList = os.listdir(path)
for file in FileList:
    if file.split('.')[-1] in extensions:
       print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from os import path
print(os.path.realpath)
extension = '.epub'
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# Making list of files with .epub extension
files = []
for directory, subdir_list, file_list in os.walk(dir_path):
    for name in file_list:
        if list(name.split("."))[1] == extension.strip("."):
            files.append(name)
```

Above code returns list of all the files with requested extension for the directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: you should rather check `[-1]` to work with filename with many dots - ie. to skip `name.pdf.zip` and keep `name.other.text.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

i would write code in bit different way where you can use pathlib.

```
import pathlib
path = r'C:\Users\PacY\Documents'
extensions = ['pdf', 'docx', 'jpg']
list(pathlib.Path(path).glob(extensions))
```

Comment: I don't have Windows but it doesn't work for me on Linux using Python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10. It needs single string in `glob()` - and it needs `*.pdf` instead of `pdf` - like `glob("*.pdf")`